# Panels with multiple rows?

Tags: nodes, panels, 7

I've got a Node/Page Panel that consists of 2 columns. What I would like to do is to have 2 rows/sections in one of the columns. I haven't found that option in layout designer, only to have a section on each side of the already existing column.

Have I missed something here?

Answer (score 0):

Just put extra panes in the column you want extra content in. Row span is something that went the way of the table ;)

If you really have to have panel sections use mini panels to add a panel with two rows within your panel with two columns.